# Convert Query into View

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, view, procedure

I have the following query and I need to store it as a view, I am lost and any help appreciated. I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2016. I have been wrestling with returning the data in a form I need using online guides but now I have it but I am unable to convert to a view.

```
    DECLARE @T AS TABLE(y INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

    DECLARE
    @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @y    AS INT,
    @sql  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

    -- Construct the column list for the IN clause
    SET @cols = STUFF(
    (SELECT N',' + QUOTENAME(y) AS [text()]
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT AttName AS y FROM vwObjectAttributesValuesAsRows)         AS Y
    ORDER BY y
    FOR XML PATH('')),
    1, 1, N'');

    -- Construct the full T-SQL statement
    -- and execute dynamically
    SET @sql = N'SELECT *
    FROM (SELECT ObjectID, ObjectName, AttName, value
    FROM vwObjectAttributesValuesAsRows 
    ) AS D
    PIVOT(Max(value) FOR AttName IN(' + @cols + N')) AS P;';

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
    GO
```

Comment: you want a dynamic number of columns?, how is that supposed to work in a view? (and with that I meant to say that you can't do it)

Comment: Is there anyway for this to update a view? Columns won't change very often so could run a stored procedure to create an updated view occasionally. Sorry to ask daft questions and thanks for the help.

Comment: You could create a job that runs every night to create the view for you in the morning with the daily  variable columns (if they vary more frequently then that then schedule the job for hourly or whatever the needs would be). The view itself cannot change columns but a if exists() drop view script that runs first and then a create view script runs would solve that problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into creating the view programmatically.. Wish me luck :)

Comment: you can't use variables in views, you can use them in stored procedures.  Are you sure you don't want a view based on the results of this stored proc?

Comment: Why exactly do you need a view instead of a stored proc? Due to the dynamic nature of the result set it would seem that a stored proc is the desired method of constructing said result set.

Comment: I have worked around this by creating a table based on the results of the stored procedure. Thank you all for your help.